# How to implement JavaScript into PHTML

Tags: javascript, php

I'm fairly new to PHP and also PHTML, how would I go about implementing JavaScript into PHTML? Here is the file i'm trying to implement it into, (viewer.phtml)

```
    <?php
    if ($type == "jpeg") {
        $stype = "jpg";
    } else {
        $stype = $type;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo APP_NAME . " - $file.$stype"; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/images/assets/css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1><?php echo "$file.$type"; ?></h1>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="/images/<?php echo "$type/$file.$stype"; ?>" alt="<?php echo "$file.$stype"; ?>">
        </div>

        <?php
            $time = microtime();
            $time = explode(' ', $time);
            $time = $time[1] + $time[0];
            $finish = $time;
            $total_time = round(($finish - $start), 4);
        ?>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a script use script tag. Inject it inside your head tag , so your head might look like this

```
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?php echo APP_NAME . " - $file.$stype"; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/images/assets/css/style.css">
        <script>
        //you Javascript code here
        </script>
    </head>
```

or

```
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title><?php echo APP_NAME . " - $file.$stype"; ?></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/images/assets/css/style.css">
           <script type="text/javascript" src="your_js_file_location_here"></script>
        </head>
```

hope this will help you

Comment: I was trying this, but nothing seemed to show up the code can be found here: http://pastebin.com/1RYvgmdU, it's supposed to show Particles.Js which the link is here: http://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/pnlso

Comment: have you tried to check the console log?i would like to know whats in there, also is your site folder contains another js folder which also contains particles.js file?

Comment: I'm currently on shared hosting so I don't have a console, and yes there is a JS folder in my site folder with particles.js

Comment: you can see console by right clicking your page then selecte inspect element and find console tab then click it

Comment: by the way though this is not part of your question you can click share in codepen.io then click Export .zip..then after downloading you will see the codes for that and you can open index.html try to see whats in the browser.. and please if my answer is correct ,mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can be added the same way you did your HTML. 
You can either add it outside of the PHP tags 
or you can use echo to output the text of your javascript.

Example 1:

```
<?php 
    //my PHP
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>alert('hello');</script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Example 2

```
     <html>
  <head>
    <script><?php echo "alert('hello');" ?></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Note that once the page or text is sent to the browser, javascript does not have access to the PHP variables directly without having to call back to the server through ajax.

Example

```
<?php 

  $message="hello";
?>
<html>
 <head>

  <script>
     //this won't work right
     alert('<?php $message ?>');</script>

  <script>
    //this will alert the value of $message at the time echo was called
    alert('<?php echo $message ?>');</script>
 </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<?php

  //!!! This won't matter to the javascript alerts, even though its PHP  value has changed. 
  $message='goodbye';

?>
```